# On Lee's proof of "Lie Subgroups are weakly embedded"

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am reading John M. Lee's **Introduction to Smooth Manifold (2nd edition)**. On page 506, Theorem 19.25 says that

> Every Lie subgroup is an integral manifold of an involutive distribution, and therefore is a weakly embedded submanifold

The proof goes like this. Suppose $G$ a Lie group and $H \subset G$ a Lie subgroup. $\text{Lie}(H)$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{h} = \iota_*(\text{Lie}(H)) \subset \text{Lie}(G)$ where $\iota: H \to G$ is the inclusion. The definition of $\iota_*(\text{Lie}(H)) \subset \text{Lie}(G)$ is $\{X \in \text{Lie}(G): X_e \in T_e H\}$. Let $D$ be the involutive distribution given by the Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$. Explicitly, $D = \bigcup_{g \in G} D_g \subset TG$ where
$$ D_g = \{X_g: X\in \mathfrak{h}\} \subset T_g G$$

Then the proof says that for each point $h \in H$, the tangent space $T_h H $ is equal to $D_h$.

I don't understand why this is a equal sign. Let the point $h$ be the identity element $e$ of $H$ for example. By the definition of $\mathfrak{h}$, it is clear that $D_e$ lives inside $T_e H$. But why the other way?

---

So now I somehow can see why $T_h H = D_h$. By definition of $D_h$ and $\mathfrak{h}$, we know that $D_g = \{X_g: X\in \text{Lie}(G), X_e \in T_e H\}$. Let $v \in T_h H$, we want to show that there is some $X_h \in D_h$ such that $D_h = v$. That is, there is some $X \in \text{Lie}(G)$ such that $X_e \in T_e H$ and $X_h = v$.

Consider the map $L_{h^{-1}}: g \mapsto h^{-1}g$ and the pushforward $L_{h^{-1}} v \in T_e H$. By Theorem 8.37 on Lee's book, there is a vector space isomorphism from $\text{Lie}(G)$ to $T_e G$ given by the evaluation map at $e$. In particular, there is an element $X \in \text{Lie}(G)$ such that $X_e =L_{h^{-1}} v$. By left-invariance, $X_h = L_h X_e = L_h L_{h^{-1}} v=v$.

Therefore, we found the left-invariant field $X$ we want.

Maybe I am too verbose but now I see why this is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $l_h: G \to G, g \mapsto hg$ be left multiplication with $h$. It is then $T_h H = dl_h(\mathfrak{h}) = \{dl_h(X) \ : \ X \in \mathfrak{h} \} = D_h$, since $X_h = dl_h(X)$ for $X \in \mathfrak{h}$.

Comment: I am a little bit confused on your nation for $X$. I thought that $X \in \mathfrak{h}$ is a left-invariant vector field. So $dl_h(X) =X$. But I agree that $D_h$ is exactly the push-forward by $dl_h$ of those $X_e \in T_e H$ such that $X \in \mathfrak{h}$. But I don't see how $T_h H \subset dl_h(\mathfrak{h})$. I only see the other way.

Comment: $\mathfrak{h}$ is identified with the left-invariant vector fields of $H$ by evaluating the left-invariant vector field $X$ of $H$ in $e$, i.e. $X \mapsto X_e$.